# dpkg error trying to install packages- "unable to open files list file for package linux-headers-generic: No such device or address"

Tags: linux, generics, installation, header

Trying to run routine updates using Mint-update (19.3 Tricia) and I'm running into an issue I haven't seen before.

When I try to install, I get the following:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to open files list file for package 'linux-headers-generic': No such device or address
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

After some Googling, I tried to manually repair by running

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

But got the same error.

I suspect the problem is a broken link or reference, as I was dropped into initramfs on boot yesterday, which required some repairs to proceed. I have no idea what links or problems to look for since I've never poked around in that sort of thing for the OS, but I did see the following:

1. linux-headers-generic.list looks ok in /var/lib/dpkg/info:

> ```
> b-w-rwx-wx 1 20033 root 243, 10 Jul 21 08:15 linux-headers-generic.list
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root  root     163 Jul  9 16:21 linux-headers-generic.md5sums
> ```

2. I also saw the following files for my current kernel if this helps:

> ```
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  803877 Jul 21 08:15 linux-headers-4.15.0-151-generic.list
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  820163 Jul  9 16:19 linux-headers-4.15.0-151-generic.md5sums
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root  root     259 Jul  9 16:19 linux-headers-4.15.0-151-generic.postinst
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root  root 1179614 Jul 21 08:15 linux-headers-4.15.0-151.list
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root  root 1482865 Jul  9 16:19 linux-headers-4.15.0-151.md5sums
> ```

No idea if this problem is connected, but these are the first install errors I've seen in a LONG time.

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt update` in order to update the package lists ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't change anything. If I then run :


sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)

or attempt to update curl (for example) from Mint Update I still get the same error